# NSMutableArray not retaining the value even after setting the property

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, uisearchbar

In my iphone app i have implemented the SearchBar on TableView.

Now the SearchBar Searches the items but the searched items are not shown in the tableview as the NSMutableArray which fills up the table with the search results is not retaining the values.

I have put the screenshot of the code and the NSLog statements for the count of copyListOfItems always return 0 even though the NSLog(@"%@",sTemp); shows the searched items in Console.

I have created the property for the NSMutableArray copyListOfItems and also synthesized it but its count in the Console is always shown as Zero.

**Here is the Code:**

```
        searchArray = [Food mutableCopy];

for (NSString *sTemp in searchArray)

     {
    NSLog(@"Value: %@",NSStringFromClass([sTemp class]));

              NSRange titleResultsRange = [sTemp rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

    if (titleResultsRange.length > 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"sTemp is:%@",sTemp);
        NSLog(@" is:%@",sTemp);
        [copyListOfItems addObject:sTemp];
        [copyListOfItems retain];

    }
         NSLog(@"Copy list count in Search Delegate Method inside For : %d",[copyListOfItems count]);
}
NSLog(@"Copy list count in Search Delegate Method : %d",[copyListOfItems count]);
[searchArray release];
searchArray = nil;
searching = YES;
[self.table reloadData];
```

de:

[image]

What should I do?

Please Help

Please Suggest

Thanks

Comment: Please post the code itself, not the screen shot of the code!

Comment: Where is the array in `copyOfListItems` created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops..!!!! Cleaned my project and build and run again and it has started working.Thanks guys for being so helpful.. :]

Answer (score 2):

From what you've said, it sounds as though the `copyListOfItems` array is never created. Synthesizing the property creates a pair of accessor methods, but doesn't automatically create an instance of `NSMutableArray` for you.

So somewhere, you'll need to call `[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]` (or some variant of `init...`), and assign the result to the instance variable, or call `[NSMutableArray array]` (or a variant of `array...`), and pass the result as an argument to the `setCopyListOfItems:` method.

Answer (score 1):

I can only assume that you're over-releasing the items in the array.  It appears that you do not have a good grip on the retain/release concept, since you're over-retaining the NSArray `copyListOfItems`.  You shouldn't be calling `-retain` on the same object within a loop since you're incrementing a single object's retain count by 1 for each iteration of the loop.

That aside, what does this code output in its NSLog() calls?  It doesn't make a lot of sense.  Why do you try to take a mutable copy of (what appears to be) a class called `Food`?

What exactly is "Food"?  An objective-C object, or an objective-C class?  This should not be compiling at all in my opinion, unless it's just very badly named.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you always alloc init the NSMutableArray. If you don't do that, all the items you add will just euhm.. disappear. So make sure you do this somewhere:

```
searchArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Comment: Are you sure the [Food mutableCopy] does exactly what you want? And also, what is th Food object?

Answer (score 0):

where are you creating the copyListOfItems Array?

I guess copyListOfItems is nil. And you are trying to add something to nil array and trying to retain the nil.

Note: whatever the operation you do on the nil will not be affected. Check whether you are creating the copyListOfItems array properly.

And why are you trying to retain the same array after adding each object?